# Get scraped data from facebook graph api using url reliably

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

My app needs to get data facebook scrapes from URLs. Up until now we were getting it using

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

Which is detailed in updating object section in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects

For example

```
POST /?id=http://google.com
{
  "url": "http://www.google.com/",
  "type": "website",
  "title": "Google",
  "image": [
  {
  "url": "http://www.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.",
  "updated_time": "2015-10-06T11:34:58+0000",
  "id": "381702034999"
}
```

Notice image section.

Unfortunately if og tags are configured wrongly on the server

```
POST /?id=http://some.page.with.bad.tags.com
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "FacebookApiException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1611016,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Object Invalid Value",
    "error_user_msg": "Object at URL 'http://some.page.with.bad.tags' of type '' is invalid because the given value '/some-bad-value' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.",
    "fbtrace_id": "abcabcabc"
  }
```

}

Which returns nothing interesting.

Attempt to GET the url returns this:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "381702034999",
    "description": "Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.",
    "title": "Google",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-10-06T11:40:04+0000",
    "url": "http://www.google.com/"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 2,
    "share_count": 13494003
  },
  "id": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

Which misses image section. I cannot find in the documentation any way to retrieve result with images without using POST /?id={url}, but that fails on any errors in og tags.

```
GET /{ObjectId}
```

returns only type and created_time

Entering the same broken link in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ results in page which contains image, description, title and captions for the page. Which I need. So it means facebook stores them, even though page has wrong tags, but I need a way to fetch them. Unfortunatelly I cannot provide link for broken url due to NDA, and I couldn't find other page with broken tags.

Comment: There is no other way of getting that information via API.

Answer (score 0):

If the page contains invalid Open Graph markup this seems expected, also do not confuse the Graph API with some sort of datasource or a scraping service you can utilize to generate the preview for web content.

If Facebook , for whatever reason, can't parse the Open Graph tags of a URL it will try to make a good guess based on the content of the page (large junks of text, images it finds, title tags etc.) to build the preview so you might get some sort of data back from `GET /{object-id}` which can just be a guess instead of actual `og:..` data.

In case you really need a more or less failsafe solution, you could build your own scraper that looks for Open Graph tags.

Comment: Expected behavior is to get og data that was valid(if one field was bad and all others were alright, which is the case), not to return only 500.

Also, Facebook has the guesses(if you paste link in debug page the guesses will appear), but there is now way to access the guesses that I could find. GET /{object-id} does NOT contain the guesses. If it did there would be no problem.

Even for pages that can be properly scrapped GET /{object-id} doesn't contain relevant information.

I can't make my scrapper with my own guessing, because my guesses wouldn't be the same as ones made by FB.

Comment: Again, this endpoint is not intended to be used as a datasource or as a service in the way you are intending to use it. Regarding the guesses, this won't result in an array of guesses, but will be filled into the appropriate field (for example title or description)

Comment: This is plain wrong. It contains pretty much nothing for those pages. `GET /{ObjectId}` returns only type and created_time for those objects that have og fields wrong. Nothing more. This is mentioned in original question.